# Is it possible to create replica of admin user

Tags: aem, jcr, crx

I am trying to impersonate user(system user) using admin session.

For admin session, I am using `repository.loginAdministrative` which is now deprecated. I dont want to use this.

Is there any other way I can replicate admin user and save the node under desired location and use the same.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.wemblog.com/2014/08/how-to-use-sessions-and-resource.html?m=1 shows how to do this on version 6 and above.

Comment: Hi, I tried giving user as admin as mentioned in blog, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create a system user with proper permissions and use the system user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created the same and added administrator group in the system user. but still I am not able to unlock page by system user. Is there separate permission for unlocking any user.